# How do I set a variable that will not be overwritten?

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax form that I'm working with. I need to detect if a user made a change to the `status` dropdown. I am attempting to set a variable thinking that the variable will still have the value I set when the form was submitted, but it does not.

How can I set a variable that will remain set so I can test against it?

```
if(typeof checkStatus == 'undefined'){
  alert('checkStatus is undefined');
  var checkStatus = status;
  // I'm expecting the next time the form is submitted, checkStatus will be set, but it's not
}else{
  if(checkStatus == status){
    alert('checkStatus is equal to ' + status);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7WU3M/

Comment: Could you post a demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, showing this working/not-working? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to explain.

Comment: you can never be fully sure, the client could modify the variable using the browser console...

Comment: Okay, but what's the problem? Are you trying to store the changed `status` variable on the client for the next page-load?

Comment: it does work... http://jsfiddle.net/7WU3M/1/

Comment: Sam, it's not working. I need to test the **last** updated value of checkStatus. It never retains the value when I resubmit the form

Comment: Does (re-)submitting the form load a new page?

Comment: No, there is no page refresh. It's all AJAX

Comment: Make sure you submit the form by AJAX. It means the form will be submitted without any reload or redirect. If it is submitted without reload/refresh, of course, the value of your variable will not be destroyed.

Comment: Can you post the form script you are using?  That is likely to narrow down your problem.

Comment: I'm using AJAX and there isn't a page reload, so I'm confused.

Comment: Would the fact that I'm using `$.post` make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If your form reloads the page (or goes somewhere else) on submit, then you would probably need to set a cookie.  A cookie would keep the variable even when a page reloads or you browse away.  Other javascript variables will be lost unless they are posted with the form and then retrieved on the next page.

You can find information on setting cookies here:
[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: I think I may just use `window.myValue`.

Comment: @NaN: you realise that won't survive past the unloading of the page?

Comment: Actually, no, I didn't. There isn't a way to do this without using a cookie? The page doesn't actually refresh, it's AJAX

Comment: You could also use server-side sessions or get/post variables depending on how your form works.  Just to check : is your checkstatus script on the form page, or on the ajax-loaded page?

Comment: It's on the ajax loaded page. It's a function actually that is loaded on pageload

Comment: On your ajax page, how are you retrieving the post data?  (May help if you post the full form and the script you are posting it to)

Comment: @DavidThomas, I have a question. A window variable is what works for me. I know they are bad to use but since it's working, does this mean that I can use a regular `var` in its place?